# Meaning of 'Energy Lease'

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Translating a short story, I'm totally stuck with this sentence:

> (the landowners) plied the land for energy leases

The story happens in an unnamed small city in the Unites States, and though there is no mention of the date, I guess it is some time around 1980.

Now, wherever I looked, I couldn't find a proper definition or description for **Energy Leases**. 
What can it mean in a context like this?

Comment: The most likely definition for "ply" here would be "to use or wield diligently" ([M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ply)).  "Energy lease" is an unfamiliar term, and I don't find a definition as such, but perhaps it refers to tax-exempt lease-purchase agreements for energy-efficiency improvements to the house, as described here: http://energy.gov/eere/slsc/leasing-arrangements

Comment: Could it be "energy leaks"?  Looking for places where the heat escapes?

Comment: Add some context from the surrounding bits of the story.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An "energy lease" is a lease on the use of some piece of real estate that allows the lessee to extract "energy" (ie, oil, gas, or coal) from the ground below.  In some cases the lease permits physical wells to be drilled on the property, while in other cases access to the oil/gas must be obtained via wells drilled on adjacent properties.

In the case of such leases for coal access the terms may allow for strip mining, leading to the destruction of any structures on the property.

Best guess for the meaning of the original sentence is that the owner let out the property for energy production, with the verb "ply" implying that he did so in a somewhat predatory fashion.

One thing to understand here is that it's often the case, in areas of the US with underground mineral resources, that a landowner will sell/lease the "mineral rights" to the property, then turn around and sell/lease the rights to build a house, eg, on the property.  This means that someone might buy a house, thinking they "own" the land on which it stands, then discover that the corporation owning the mineral rights can legally tear down the house to access the minerals.

There are many scenarios where corporate ownership of "mineral rights" can result in the legalized robbery of an individual citizen.

Comment: Rather bizarrely though, although a big chunk of your answer is devoted to the sharp practice of selling "mineral rights" (and presumably, wind-farm "energy rights") separately from the building itself, OP's specific text refers to the ***house***. I don't know about AmE, but in BrE you could use ***the property*** to reference building+surrounding land, and thus you'd naturally talk about retaining / renting the *property* (not the *house*) if the reason was to capitalise on the mineral or energy potential.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - We (alas) don't know the context of the sentence.  The wording I *can* see makes me suspicious that the context is with regard to the landowner effectively abusing the rights of the residents of the house, as a result of the energy leases.  The wording likely does not immediately reflect the precise legal situation.

Comment: Thank you, I went with your description but had to add a footnote, and mentioned your name there

Comment: @HotLicks, and I updated the question.

Comment: @FumbleFingers you were right in your comment about **the house**. That was my mistake

Comment: @Alireza: Thanks for letting me know that (it's always nice to have one's speculations confirmed! :) But I'm not sure the question justifies *reopening*, because it seems to me the first paragraph of HotLicks' answer here should cover everything you need to know re "energy leases".

Answer (score 2):

Tenative answer. If someone with definitive knowledge can give a more authoritative answer, I gladly yield. :-)

An "energy lease" is when you rent your property for use in producing energy. For example, you might allow a power company to put an electric windmill in your backyard. Or you might allow an oil company to drill for oil.

To "ply" means to do something diligently or repeatedly. Like, "The plumber plied his trade", meaning, he did plumbing work regularly. Or, "My daughter plied me with questions", meaning, she asked lots of questions.

But here I run into a problem with the sentence you quote. How would you "ply for leases"? The intent might be that they diligently searched for opportunities to rent out the property for energy production. That's not the way the word "ply" is normally used. But maybe that's how the word is used in some regional dialect. Or maybe that's a common usage in the energy industry.

Perhaps if you gave more of the context the meaning would become clear.